# wso2 API visibility for subscriber

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

using wso2 AM 1.10 I published an API logged in as the default admin user. I tried to create a new user using the management console and assigned the Subsriber role to that user. However when i log in to the store using that user, the published API is not visible. I made sure that the API is set to public while publishing the API. Also, I dont see the options in the manage tab as described here. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-APIvisibilityandsubscription

What could be the reason for the newly created subsriber not able to view the pubslished API? What is the criteria for the API to show up in store for the newly created subscriber?

Comment: 1) Are you sure admin can see it? 2) Does this happen for every new user or for this particular one only? 3) Is this a single node setup?

Comment: This is a distributed set and yes admin can see it

Comment: answer for 2) ?

Comment: apart from the default admin, I have set up only one other user as a subscriber

Comment: unrelated to this question. I have another question. I have a distributed set up running one docker container each for worker, manager, publisher etc. I have also set up a proxy through Nginx. I deployed the sample caluclator API and when I tried to access the API i get a 404. What could be the issue? All I see in the logs is "Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., "

Answer (score 0):

For APIs to be visible, the API needs to be in published state and the [user's role needs to have subscriber permissions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+User+Roles).